# How to create toast in android inside asyntask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have did this :

```
doInBackground(String... prams){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Server too busy. Please try after sometime.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

Getting error . please help.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: This - 12-23 15:45:30.548: W/System.err(3596): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: add that line in onPostExecute()

Comment: Code crash when error comes, onPostExecute() not called.

Comment: use onPreExecute() and onPostExecute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update UI inside doInBackground.Do this to show toast

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Server too busy. Please try after sometime.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

It will solve your problem

Comment: why its is happen.Toast is not work in Asyctask and works in runOnUiThread

Comment: because Toast runs on Ui thread and Async task starts new thread  so it gives exception

Answer (score 1):

You can't show toast in

```
doInBackground(String... prams){}
```

[image]