# AsyncTask not updating UI after doInBackground finishes

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to make a simple app that's looks for WiFi networks, and connects to them. I'm currently having a problem with updating the UI.

A few pointers would be great. Thank you for your time.

```
class UiUpdater extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<ScanResult>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        TextView searching = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.searching);
        searching.setText("Currently searching...");
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ScanResult> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) Client.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        if (!manager.isWifiEnabled())
            manager.setWifiEnabled(true);

        return manager.getScanResults();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ScanResult> items) {
        super.onPostExecute(items);

        ArrayList<Items> wifi = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ScanResult s : items)
            wifi.add(new Items(s.SSID, s.capabilities));

        ///TextView searching = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.searching);
        ///searching.setText("");

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        Explorer adapter = new Explorer(Client.this, R.layout.listview_item_row, wifi);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        clickListener(list, wifi);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having exactly?  Are you receiving an error?  Is there an error log?

Comment: I don't get any errors, it just won't update the UI, no matter how long I wait.

Comment: Have you verified that you are getting any `ScanResult`s being returned from your doInBackground ?

Comment: Is onPostExecute being called?  If not, then it seems like getScanResults never returns.  If it is, then the problem is likely in your adapter.

Comment: Yep, I tried 'if(wifi!=null)', apparently it returns something.

Comment: How can I check if onPostExecute is called?

Comment: Have you made a call to `startScan()` ?  See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#startScan()

Comment: I also tried that, still nothing. My fear is that somehow doInBackground finishes earlier, and some other thread holds the getScanResults, but since doInBackground finishes earlier it also calls onPostExecute earlier.

Comment: have you tried invalidating the list?

Comment: Nope, should I have?

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433282/how-to-create-toast-in-android-inside-asyntask/34433575#34433575

Comment: I got it to work, I posted how below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working, but by taking a different approach.

I used the `BroadcastReceiver` and `registerReceiver` to get the `onReceive` event to update the list.

Here's the code:

```
    mWifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if(!mWifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
        mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    mWifiManager.startScan();

    wifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent)
        {
            if(mWifiManager != null) {
                List<ScanResult> networks = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
                showWifi(networks);
            }
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
```

Although I haven't managed to understand how `AsyncTask` works, I did get some nice results with loading a simple progress bar.

I think the problem I encountered was as such:

1. I started an `AsyncTask` on another thread.
2. In the `doInBackground`, `getScanResults` started another background thread, leading `doInBackground` to think the job's done.
3. `onPostExecute` was called because `doInBackground` finished its job.

Bottom line, it wasn't the `AsyncTask`'s fault, it was mine for not knowing that `getScanResults` starts another background thread.

Answer (score 1):

please use Toast message or logcat or breakpoint to check onPost execute is being called or not

Comment: I just checked onPostExecute is called and it can't be my adapter because if I enter some dummy text, it will show it with ease.

Comment: your view should update i suspect your arraylist of wifi size is zero mean your getScanResult return nothing that why you can not see your view being update